# How to add missing fonts to Adobe Illustrator?

Tags: osx-lion, fonts, adobe-illustrator, adobe-acrobat

When opening an Adobe Acrobat PDF document on Mac OS X Lion to edit in Adobe Illustrator CS6, I got the message:

> The font Helvetica-Narrow-Bold is missing.  Affected text will be displayed using a substitute font.
>   The font QuickTypePi is missing.  Affected text will be displayed using a substitute font.

How can I provide the missing fonts so that no substitution occurs and upon return to Adobe Acrobat Pro X the original fonts will remain after any edits in Illustrator?

Or, since the message talks about their display, will the font remain unchanged upon return to Adobe Acrobat?

Comment: Which operating system are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- If they are free fonts, you will get them on [DaFont](http://www.dafont.com). To me, both seem like proprietary fonts, so once you get them downloaded, read on.
- Search with the font names the error is showing you.
- Once you get the font files downloaded, extract the `.zip` if its conpressed.
- The font files are in `.ttf` format.
- Just double click on the `.ttf` file and install it. Any other extension also use the same procedure. And restart your Illustrator.
- Attaching a screenshot.

[image: Installing]

**Update**:
The fonts will remain the same when you open it in Adobe Reader, since the font files are normally embedded in the PDF itself.

---

**Update 2:**

I'm attaching the screenshots, of the error msg your getting but will not make any changes to you PDF file if you quit (Assuming you did not edit anything in Illustrator)

[image: Font Error]

If you do make changes, you will get this dialog box while closing the file or quitting Illustrator. Click <kbd>Don't Save</kbd> Screenshot below.

[image: Don't Save]

If you do not make any changes you will **NOT** get this dialog, and **NO** changes will be made to your original file.

Comment: I'm wondering if install is even necessary?  Upon return to Acrobat, will the original fonts be restored?

Comment: @WilliamKF yes it's a PDF, it will remain the same when you return back to the Reader. Just don't save the file on quitting Illustrator if it asks you too.(in worse case) I have also updated my answer.

Comment: Hmm, I thought you had to "Save" in Illustrator in order for your edits to become visible in Acrobat?  Note that Illustrator is only editing one page at a time, not the entire Acrobat file.

Comment: That's fine, no changes are made to the file till you make explicit changes to the file. I have added another update to my answer, have a look!

Comment: But I do need my changes to be reflected back in Acrobat, unless I "Save" the changes are not reflected.

Comment: @WilliamKF Okie just tried doing it, edit the text and saving it, does NOT affect the font used. In reader it will show the original font. So go ahead and save the changes. Just make a copy of the PDF, just to be safe, and help you compare it visually just for the sake of it after making the changes.

Comment: For me, I am getting font change, at least the flow layout is messed up.  It appears it stopped using narrow font for helvetica and now the text overruns where it should be on the tax form.

Comment: If you want to do major edits on existing PDF files, you should use Adobe Acrobat Professional, Illustrator is not the software for it. Or if you think you need to do it in Illustrator itself, you will need to get the font files.